# gradle exclude aidl source file after compilation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle, aidl

I am using Gradle assembleRelease and have some aidl in my project, but I find the aidl source code files are in the release apk. I would like to have these source files been excluded. How could I achieve that? Thank you.